# Twitter-Bootstrap: login form in navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to place a login inline-form in a twitter navbar.

I have done this but I don't manage to push the form right...
http://jsfiddle.net/v34Sv/

All twitter components (span, offset, pull-right) fail and I am worried loosing the responsive component when using an absolute position.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The button is not in the perfect place but at least the form is inline (I hope it helps).

```
<div class='navbar'>
 <div class='navbar-inner'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <a class='brand'>Test</a>
        <ul class='nav'>
            <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-search pull-right">
            <input type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Login">
            <input type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn"/>
        </form>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: fyi this would fix the alignment: `style="margin-top: 0px; vertical-align: top;"`
And for those rocking MVC: `@Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account", new { @class = "btn", @style="margin-top: 0px; vertical-align: top;" })`

(Or use class navbar-form" from below ;)

Comment: This does not align the button properly.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão Try the answer below

Answer (score 12):

form inline with button in the right place

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class='navbar'>
    <div class='navbar-inner'>
        <div class='container-fluid'>
            <a class='brand'>Test</a>
            <ul class='nav'>
                <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form pull-right">
                <input type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Login">
                <input type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Password">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 this is really the correct answer, as it requires no additional fix for the button alignment

Answer (score 4):

The class navbar-form is made for just this.

```
<form class="navbar-form form-inline pull-right">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Taken from http://examples.getbootstrap.com/jumbotron/index.html?

Comment: Looks like the link is dead

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```
<div class='navbar'>
  <div class='navbar-inner'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    <a class='brand'>Test</a>
    <ul class='nav nav-collapse collapse'>
        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>

    </ul>
    <ul class='nav nav-collapse collapse pull-right'>
        <li class=""><form class="navbar-search">
        <input type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Login">
        <input type="text" class="span2" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn"/>
    </form></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

​

**CSS:**

```
form.login {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

form.login input {
  height: 14px;
  width: 140px;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .navbar-search .btn {
    margin:-9px 0 0 0;
  }
}
```

**jsFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/baptme/v34Sv/5/